# Delete, drop, kill ALL factor levels from Dataframe

Tags: r, factors, levels

Lets take mtcars as example and create a new variable:

```
mtcars$name <-  rownames(mtcars)
mtcars[,] <- lapply(mtcars, factor)
mtcars[,] <- lapply(mtcars, as.numeric)
```

Now the names are converted into numerics which i definitely dont want

```
> mtcars
                    mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb name
Mazda RX4            16   2   13 11   16  9    6  1  2    2    4   18
Mazda RX4 Wag        16   2   13 11   16 12   10  1  2    2    4   19
Datsun 710           19   1    6  6   15  7   22  2  2    2    1    5
Hornet 4 Drive       17   2   16 11    5 16   24  2  1    1    1   13
Hornet Sportabout    13   3   23 15    6 18   10  1  1    1    2   14
Valiant              12   2   15  9    1 19   29  2  1    1    1   31
Duster 360            3   3   23 20    7 21    5  1  1    1    4    7
Merc 240D            20   1   12  2   11 15   27  2  1    2    2   21
```

## How can i convert factors back into the right formats.(char,log,num ...) ?

Comment: which you can find in `help("factor")` under "Warning".

Comment: R FAQ 7.10: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f

Comment: that's exactly what the duplicate question addresses.  Identify which columns are factors, then only apply the conversion to those columns.

Comment: then they shouldn't have a problem.  Since *all* columns are now factors, they want them all converted back to numeric.  I'm not clear on the question ... ???

Comment: I think its not possible to do what i want. I thought factor levels are something beeing added to a type (like num, char ...). But factors are a own type. How can R ever know when going away from factor what was originaly a num and what is char.

Comment: I think you still haven't clarified your question sufficiently.  It's true that if I start with `dd <- data.frame(x1=c("5","6","7","8"),x2=5:8)`, then do `dd2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(dd,factor))`, there's no way to get back from `dd2` to `dd`. On the other hand, if I start from `dd <- data.frame(x1=c("a","b","c","d"),x2=5:8)`, I *can* probably figure it out, because I can establish that `x1` can't be successfully be converted back to numeric (`as.numeric(as.character(dd2$x1))` will give `NA` values and a warning).  ...

Comment: If what I described in the previous comment is what you want, though, you need to give a **reproducible example that illustrates your point** - trying to read your mind is frustrating ...

Comment: I would suggest that you take a shot at editing your answer below (which isn't an answer ...) into your question -- then we can re-open the question and try to answer it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that `type.convert` would suit your needs. It coerces its input to the most basic data type that can represent it. Thus, it would turn a character column that contains numbers that can be represented as integer into an integer column.

```
mtcars$name <-  rownames(mtcars)
str(mtcars)
# 'data.frame': 32 obs. of  12 variables:
# $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
# $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
# $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
# $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
# $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
# $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
# $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
# $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
# $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
# $ name: chr  "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...

mtcars[,] <- lapply(mtcars, factor)
str(mtcars)
# 'data.frame': 32 obs. of  12 variables:
# $ mpg : Factor w/ 25 levels "10.4","13.3",..: 16 16 19 17 13 12 3 20 19 14 ...
# $ cyl : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ...
# $ disp: Factor w/ 27 levels "71.1","75.7",..: 13 13 6 16 23 15 23 12 10 14 ...
# $ hp  : Factor w/ 22 levels "52","62","65",..: 11 11 6 11 15 9 20 2 7 13 ...
# $ drat: Factor w/ 22 levels "2.76","2.93",..: 16 16 15 5 6 1 7 11 17 17 ...
# $ wt  : Factor w/ 29 levels "1.513","1.615",..: 9 12 7 16 18 19 21 15 13 18 ...
# $ qsec: Factor w/ 30 levels "14.5","14.6",..: 6 10 22 24 10 29 5 27 30 19 ...
# $ vs  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
# $ am  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ gear: Factor w/ 3 levels "3","4","5": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
# $ carb: Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
# $ name: Factor w/ 32 levels "AMC Javelin",..: 18 19 5 13 14 31 7 21 20 22 ...


mtcars[,] <- lapply(mtcars, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), as.is = TRUE))
str(mtcars)
#'data.frame':  32 obs. of  12 variables:
#$ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#$ cyl : int  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#$ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
#$ hp  : int  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#$ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#$ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#$ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#$ vs  : int  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#$ am  : int  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#$ gear: int  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#$ carb: int  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
#$ name: chr  "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
```

If you don't store the original column classes before you turn the columns into factors, there is no way to restore this information completely. However, that shouldn't be necessary anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(x = factor(1:10)
                 ,y = factor(1:10))

str(df)

df[,] <- lapply(df, function(x) {as.numeric(as.character(x))})

str(df)
```

result

```
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
$ x: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ y: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Try that with `x = factor(2:11)`

Comment: Corrected it, but comment on question is similar

Comment: This works fine if all cols are num in first place. Like in this example.